# PHP: Invalid file

Tags: php, file, video

I have a section in which the user can upload a video or images, here is my solution

HTML

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <label for="file">
      <span>Filename:</span>
   </label>
   <input type="file" name="file" id="file" /> <br />
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

PHP

```
<?php

   $allowedExts = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png", "mp3", "mp4", "wma");
   $extension = pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

if ((
     ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "video/mp4")
     ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "audio/mp3")
     ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "audio/wma")
     ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
     ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
     ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
    ) 
    && 
    ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 50000)
    && 
    in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
  {
     if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
        echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
     } else {
       echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
       echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
       echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
       echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />";

     if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])) {
        echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
     } else {
       move_uploaded_file(
         $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
         "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
       echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
      }
    }
  } else {
     echo "Invalid file";
  }
?>
```

I can upload images, but when I upload a video I am getting the following error

> Invalid file

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: What is the file type & size?

Comment: it enters in the else part, so just check why does not pass the if

Comment: my file is mp4 and its 2mb? I tested even 1mb ?? weird

Comment: `print_r($_FILES['file'])` it's simple, isn't it?

Comment: @u_mulder where exactly do I need to add that?

Comment: check format of your video .

Comment: please make sure to increase post_max_size AND load_max_filesize AND memory_limit

Comment: @AmiteshKumar my video format is mp4

Answer (score 0):

Mos of people and StackOverflow solutions suggested adding.

`post_max_size AND load_max_filesize AND memory_limit`

But that was not the problem for me here is what I changed

from  this `&&($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 50000)`

to this  `&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 5000000)`

Now everything works fine